# jquery/tablesorter header disabled if date column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using jquery/tablesorter for my table whose columns are a mix of text and digits. Everything was working fine. Next, I added a new date column and now the headers are completely disabled. i.e, I can't sort on any columns. I fired up firebug and I see an error when the page loads:

**s.replace is not a function** in the below code

```
this.formatFloat = function (s) {
  var i = parseFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
  return (isNaN(i)) ? 0 : i;
};
```

When I put a breakpoint and see the value of s, for date column, it is some number like 736283783 whereas for all others it is a string like "1" or "123". I have tried different formats for date like "dd/mm/yy", "dd-mm-yyyy", "Jan 1st 2011" etc. with no luck.

Update: The above code is in jquery.tablesorter.js. It is not the code I wrote.

My table source looks like this:

```
<table id="historyTable" class="fullwidth sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Start</th>
                <th>End</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Keyword</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
             <tr>
                <td>Active</td>
                <td>2008-09-18</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>TF</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Inactive</td>
                <td>2010-09-18</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>ZX</td>
             </tr>
       </table>
```

My JS code is just invoking tablesorter like this: 
    jQuery("table.sortable").tablesorter();
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can post the HTML and JS tht can give a little better perspective?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
this.formatFloat = function (s) {
  // add .toString() to convert it to a string
  var i = parseFloat(s.toString().replace(/,/g, ''));
  return (isNaN(i)) ? 0 : i;
};
```

maybe it wouldnt work because `s` is not a [string](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)?

Update; 
so something like this:

```
this.formatFloat = function (s) {
  // add .toString() to convert it to a string<br/>
  var strDate = new Date(s.toString().replace(/,/g, ''));   
  var i = parseFloat(strDate);

  return (isNaN(i)) ? 0 : i;
};
```

Comment: updated the question. That code is in jquery.tablesorter.js. Yeah, you are right. s is not a string which is what is causing the problem but not sure where/how to fix it.

Comment: Just convert [it back to a date](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Convert-String-to-Date.aspx)

Comment: they wanna return a float, watch my update... first convert it to string after that convert it back to a date and after all they parse it to a float

Comment: @Mahesh: Did you try what Tricker suggested, I tried it and its working. What is the other error/issue you are having?

Comment: I think I am almost there. When I pass in a date object, it seem to work fine. Although, my table content looks like this <tr>Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:01 GMT-0600 (CST)</tr>. If I format it and display as "mm/dd/yy", it doesn't work. Just to be clear, I am getting the date value dynamically. Here is my rails code mixed with js: start = new Date(<%= stat[:campaign].start_at.ergo.to_date %>)

Comment: Try: new Date(<%= stat[:campaign].start_at.ergo.to_date %>).getTime()

This is how they calling it in the source code!